# PLCrashReporter not catching certain ABORT signals

Tags: iphone, crash-reports, plcrashreporter

I am using PLCrashReporter in one of iOS app for Crash Reporting. Below is my sample crashing scenario that I am using to test PL.

`NSArray *array = [NSArray array];
[array objectAtIndex:23];`

which is working fine and reporting the crash properly. However, if I change my crashing scenario to

`strcpy(0,"abc");`

PL is not able to detect it. I can see Apple catching the crash and showing it in XCode when I connect my device.

Is it other than "/crashes/" directory by PL? In both cases, the final signal thrown is SIGABRT(not sure about the underlying signal). Can anyone provide any lead on what is happening here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing more about what you're doing; specifically, the code that you're using to enable the reporter and verify that it is working.

Comment: Thanks Landon for replying. I have a helper class that invokes PL via the following code
`<code>
PLCrashReporter *crashReporter = [PLCrashReporter sharedReporter];

//checking if we previously crashed
if([crashReporter hasPendingCrashReport]){
[self handleCrashReport];
}

if(![crashReporter enableCrashReporterAndReturnError: &error]){
NSLog(@"Error: PL initialization failed!");
}
</code>`
Please let me know if you need any more info. I am using the 1.1-rc2 version of PL. It was otherwise working fine and in almost all scenarios, until recently, we discovered this test scenario.

Comment: We have double checked the integration code from http://www.clintharris.net/2009/plcrashreporter-a-handy-api-for-reporting-iphone-app-crashes/ which we had used initially for integration

Comment: If you can send an example case to the PLCrashReporter mailing list, I can take a look directly. https://groups.google.com/group/plcrashreporter?pli=1 -- otherwise, if you can include the test case in your question, I can follow up here, too.

Comment: I have a sample crashing application for testing PL.
It has a view that loads on a button click and crashes.The crashing scenario is in the viewDidLoad method. Following is the crashing code:
'<code>
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   
   strcpy(0, "abc");
   
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}</code>'

When I run the test application, it crashes on executing the above code, but on next application launch, PL does not report a crash.

Please let me know if you need more info around reproducing the mentioned scenario.